# map RxMoya Single Response to RxSwift Observable Result

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I am trying to map a `Single<Response>` to a an `Observable<Result<CustomObject, MoyaError>>` however I am unsure about how to do it.

My current function is as follows:

```
    func accountInfo() -> Observable<AccountInfo> {
        return provider
                .rx
                .request(.accountInfo)
                .map(AccountInfo.self)
                .asObservable()
    }
```

However, I would like something as follows:

```
    func accountInfo() -> Observable<Result<AccountInfo, MoyaError>> {
        return provider
                .rx
                .request(.accountInfo)
                .mapResult(AccountInfo.self)
                .asObservable()
    }
```

Any help creating a `mapResult` extension would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
extension Single {
    var asObservableResult: Observable<Result<Element, Error>> {
        return asObservable()
            .map { .success($0) }
            .catchError { .just(.failure($0)) }
    }
}
```

Although it might make more sense to map it to a Driver rather than an Observable... Otherwise, you have two possible errors...

```
extension Single {
    var asDriverResult: Driver<Result<Element, Error>> {
        return asObservable()
            .map { .success($0) }
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { .just(.failure($0)) })
    }
}
```